# How to exit from a specific function in PHP?

Tags: php

I have multiple nested methods inside a PHP class. What I want to do is, based on certain circumstances, I want to exit from NOT JUST the current method, but 2 above it, then the leftover code should continue running. Now the issue with die(), exit() is that they end the full script and I don't want that. I simply want to go a few methods up and continue the script.

Of course, there's the old school method of returning a value in each method and check if it's false for example. But that way I'll have to write tons of additional code if I have like 50 nested methods. Here's what I have right now - it's a very basic usage here, I'm using it in a lot more complicated scenarios (using PHP 7.2.4):

```
class Sites
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fn1();
    }

    public function fn1()
    {   
        $fn2 = $this->fn2();

        echo 'I want this to be displayed no matter what!';
    }

    public function fn2()
    {       
        $fn3 = $this->fn3();

        if ($fn3)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function fn3()
    {       
        $fn4 = $this->fn4();

        if ($fn4)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function fn4()
    {       
        $random = rand(1, 100);

        if ($random > 50)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // I want to exit/break the scirpt to continue running after
            // the $fn2 = $this->fn2() call in the $this->fn1() function.
            exit();

            echo "This shouldn't be displayed.";
        }
    }
}
```

Just as mentioned in the code comments, I want to break the script - if the random number is below 50 and go back to `fn1()` but continue executing the `echo` function there.

Is this possible somehow? Please let me know if you need more information and I'll provide.

Comment: Like... `return`?

Comment: _"the old school method of returning a value"_ - who said that's old school? And what's wrong with it?

Comment: @JonStirling I know it's possible with returns but then I'd have to write lots of them. If I'd have 50 functions I would need to write + handle returns for all of them. I'm looking for a way to shorten that.

Comment: If you had 50 nested methods you've got something a lot more serious wrong that whether to use returns...

Comment: what happened to return ?

Comment: you can just `return $random > 50;` in your last method. And `return $this->fn4();` in the others (except the first one)

Comment: I'm reluctant to suggest this... but, [goto](http://php.net/goto)?

Comment: I have to agree the other comments, if you have that many nested functions there may be something wrong with the design. That being said, maybe a specific `Exception` with a `try catch` in your upper functions may help you out there.

Comment: Yes I agree that if I have that many nested methods, that's not really ideal, but in a big application framework, it's more than possible. Anyways I'm actually looking for a solution similar to what @JonStirling mentioned - `goto` but I don't think that it's going to work for me if I'm using a lot of different classes and methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Exceptions to do this, not particularly elegant, but this should do what your after, replace these methods...

```
public function fn1()
{
    try {
        $fn2 = $this->fn2();
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )  {
    }

    echo 'I want this to be displayed no matter what!';
}


public function fn4()
{
    $random = rand(1, 100);

    if ($random > 50)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // I want to exit/break the scirpt to continue running after
        // the $fn2 = $this->fn2() call in the $this->fn1() function.
        //exit();
        throw new Exception();

        echo "This shouldn't be displayed.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

How about regular function call with a `flag`?

```
class Sites
{
    protected $flag  = false; 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fn1();
    }


    public function fn1()
    {

        if ($this->flag) {
            $this->flag = true;

        } else {
            echo 'I want this to be displayed no matter what!';
            $fn2 = $this->fn2();
        }

    }

    public function fn2()
    {       
        $fn3 = $this->fn3();

        if ($fn3)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function fn3()
    {       
        $fn4 = $this->fn4();

        if ($fn4)
        {

            return true;
        }
    }


public function fn4()
{
    $random = rand(1, 100);

    if ($random > 50)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // I want to exit/break the scirpt to continue running after
        // the $fn2 = $this->fn2() call in the $this->fn1() function.
        //exit();
        $this->flag = true;
        $this->fn1();
        exit();

        echo "This shouldn't be displayed.";
    }
}
}

$sites = new Sites;
```

I hope this helps!